# Python :Replace repetitive line in a file with empty space but not on first / last occurrence

Tags: python-2.7, file

I have a file which has repetitive lines `<this is repeated>` that I would like to replace with empty space `""`. However, the first occurrence or last occurrence of the repeated line does not need to be replaced. I tried `replace()` before but this function will replace all the strings in the file. Is there any way to write it to get the expected result? *Ps: It is a large text file*

The file is as follow:
`<this is repeated>`
`second line`
`another lines`
`third line`
`<this is repeated>`
`<this is repeated>`

Comment: Read the lines of the file and compare the lines... if the current line is different from the last, write it to your output file, otherwise skip it and write a blank line... there isn't much more to it...

Comment: would it replace it with an empty line or remove the whole line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I realized after posting that if the last occurrence was the very last line without a `\n` after this technique would leave it as well as the next last occurrence.

First you would need to iterate over the file until you find the first occurrence:

```
file = <OPEN FILE>
rep_line = "<this is repeated>\n"

beginning = "" #record all data until found
while True: #broken when rep_line is found in file (or end of file is reached)
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
         raise EOFError("reached end of file before finding first occurence")
    beginning+=line
    if line == rep_line:
        break

rest = file.read() #you can read the rest after iterating over a few lines
```

Then you will have `beginning` which contains everything up to and including the first occurrence, and the `rest`

So all you need to do with `rest` is to `count` how may time it occurs and replace all but the last one:

```
reps = rest.count(rep_line)

new_text = beginning + rest.replace(rep_line,"",reps - 1)
                                               #     ^ don't replace the last one
```

however this direct approach will pick up lines that end with the text (like `"hello <this is repeated>"` for example) and this can be fixed by also checking that there is a \n right before the line:

```
reps = rest.count("\n"+rep_line)

new_text = beginning + rest.replace("\n"+rep_line,"\n",reps - 1)
                                                  # ^ replace with a single newline
```

Comment: if you want to replace it with an empty line instead of removing completely just replace it with `"\n"` or for last example `"\n\n"` to leave the empty line.

Comment: I got this error "Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data" at line rest = file.read(). Do you know why?

Comment: well I'm assuming because you are not just doing `open("my_file.txt")` or you are and have `from LIBRARY import *` with a library that has a `open` function, either way I edited answer to use `file.readline()` instead since that is probably better anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. It got what I need.